# Selective iteration in arbitrary number of lists

Tags: python

Let's say I have an arbitrary number of lists (so list of lists). All lists are of same size,
An example of this might be

```
say, k lists of length 4 (k=2)
[
[A, B, C, D] # length 4
[A, F, G, D] # length 4
]
```

Now given a query_list

```
[A, B, C, E]
```

This should return `[A, B, C, D]` which is the longest chain as in `[A,F,G,D]`, the second character "F" and "B" in query_list mismatches..

Comment: I don't see a question here.  What is your question?

Comment: Instead of using a list of list using a `trie` is perhaps what you want.

Comment: do you need to check which list matched the most....?

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali yes..

Comment: you can use collection library

Comment: do you want all match list or 1st matched list

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali 1st is fine.. incase of multiple just return any match (random or first)

Comment: try the given program below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=[ ["a","b","c"],["a","b","z"],["a","z","c"] ]
z=["a","b","c"]

arr = []
for i in x:
    cnt = sum(z == y for z, y in zip(i, z))
    arr.append(cnt)  
    
index = arr.index(max(arr))

print(x[index],"matched the most")
```